Error in connection between SQLite class and SQL Server class in Android Java
I have managed to create a local SQLite database to insert data, read it and update it. The problem is in a class where I do the communication test with SQL Server, there I can't pull the data from sql lite that are stored the communication data (if I put them directly, I don't have a problem)
Below is the error:
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.io.File android.content.Context.getDatabasePath(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
2024-12-05 21:36:00.969 13284-13337 System.err              com.example.midasitemcatalog         W      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:352)
2024-12-05 21:36:00.969 13284-13337 System.err              com.example.midasitemcatalog         W      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:322)
2024-12-05 21:36:00.969 13284-13337 System.err              com.example.midasitemcatalog         W      at Queries.SQLite.readConnetion(SQLite.java:67)
2024-12-05 21:36:00.969 13284-13337 System.err              com.example.midasitemcatalog         W      at MidasConnetion.MSSQLConnection.connectionclass(MSSQLConnection.java:28)
2024-12-05 21:36:00.970 13284-13337 System.err              com.example.midasitemcatalog         W      at Queries.SQLQueries.getItemsFragments(SQLQueries.java:287)
2024-12-05 21:36:00.970 13284-13337 System.err              com.example.midasitemcatalog         W      at fragments.ItemListFragment$RetrieveDataAsyncTask.doInBackground(ItemListFragment.java:353)
2024-12-05 21:36:00.970 13284-13337 System.err              com.example.midasitemcatalog         W      at fragments.ItemListFragment$RetrieveDataAsyncTask.doInBackground(ItemListFragment.java:326)
2024-12-05 21:36:00.970 13284-13337 System.err              com.example.midasitemcatalog         W      at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:333)
2024-12-05 21:36:00.970 13284-13337 System.err              com.example.midasitemcatalog         W      at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
2024-12-05 21:36:00.971 13284-13337 System.err              com.example.midasitemcatalog         W      at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:245)
2024-12-05 21:36:00.971 13284-13337 System.err              com.example.midasitemcatalog         W      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
2024-12-05 21:36:00.971 13284-13337 System.err              com.example.midasitemcatalog         W      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
2024-12-05 21:36:00.971 13284-13337 System.err              com.example.midasitemcatalog         W      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)

First my sqlite class
package Queries;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class SQLite extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "midasandroid.db";
    private static final int DB_Version = 1;
    private static final String local_Data = "Configure";
    private static final String id = "id";
    private static final String dbDomainName = "dbDomainName";
    private static final String dbname = "dbname";
    private static final String dbPort  = "dbPort";
    private static final String dbUser = "dbUser";
    private static final String dbPassword = "dbPassword";
    private static final String currentMetPrice = "currentMetPrice";
    private static final String apikey = "apikey";
    private Context context;



    public SQLite(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DB_Version);
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String sql = "CREATE TABLE " + local_Data + "("
                + id + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
                + dbDomainName + " TEXT,"
                + dbPort + " TEXT,"
                + dbname + " TEXT,"
                + dbUser + " TEXT,"
                + dbPassword + " TEXT,"
                + apikey + " TEXT,"
                + currentMetPrice + " REAL)";
        db.execSQL(sql);

    }

    public void addValuesCon(String dbDomainName, String dbname, String dbPort, String dbUser, String dbPassword) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(this.id, 1);
        values.put(this.dbDomainName, dbDomainName);
        values.put(this.dbPort, dbPort);
        values.put(this.dbname, dbname);
        values.put(this.dbUser, dbUser);
        values.put(this.dbPassword, dbPassword);
        values.put(this.apikey, "");
        values.put(this.currentMetPrice, 0);
        db.insert(local_Data, null, values);
        db.close();

    }

    public ArrayList<LocalData> readConnetion() {
        ArrayList<LocalData> localData = new ArrayList<>();
        SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + local_Data, null);
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                localData.add(new LocalData(cursor.getString(0),
                        cursor.getString(1),
                        cursor.getString(2),
                        cursor.getString(3),
                        cursor.getString(4),
                        cursor.getString(5),
                        cursor.getString(6),
                        cursor.getFloat(7)));
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        cursor.close();
        return  localData;
    }

    public ArrayList<LocalData> readMetPrice() {
        ArrayList<LocalData> localData = new ArrayList<>();
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + local_Data, null);
        if (cursor!=null) {
            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                localData.add(new LocalData(cursor.getString(1),
                        cursor.getString(2),
                        cursor.getString(3),
                        cursor.getString(4),
                        cursor.getString(5),
                        cursor.getString(6),
                        cursor.getString(7),
                        cursor.getFloat(8)));
            }
        }
        cursor.close();
        return  localData;
    }

    public void updateDataConnection(int id, String dbDomainName, String dbname, String dbPort, String dbUser, String dbPassword){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

        values.put(this.dbDomainName, dbDomainName);
        values.put(this.dbname, dbname);
        values.put(this.dbPort, dbPort);
        values.put(this.dbUser, dbUser);
        values.put(this.dbPassword, dbPassword);

        db.update(local_Data, values, "id = ?", new String[]{String.valueOf(id)});
        db.close();
    }

    public void updateDataMetPrice(int id,String apikey, float currentMetPrice){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

        values.put(this.apikey, apikey);
        values.put(this.currentMetPrice, currentMetPrice);

        db.update(local_Data, values, "id = ?", new String[]{String.valueOf(id)});
        db.close();
    }


    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + local_Data);
        onCreate(db);
    }
}


My SQL Server connetion
package MidasConnetion;




import android.content.Context;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.util.Log;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import Queries.LocalData;
import Queries.SQLite;
import Queries.SQLtoSQLite;

public class MSSQLConnection {
    private Context context;
    public MSSQLConnection(Context context){
        this.context = context;
    }

    public Connection connectionclass() {

        Connection connection = null;
        SQLite sqLite = new SQLite(context);
        ArrayList<LocalData> localData1 = sqLite.readConnetion();
        if (!localData1.isEmpty()){
            LocalData localData = localData1.get(0);
            String classDriver="net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver";
            String serverID="jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://"+localData.getDbDomainName()+":"+localData.getDbPort()+"/"+localData.getDbname();
            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
            try {
                Class.forName(classDriver);
                DriverManager.getLoginTimeout();
                connection = DriverManager.getConnection(serverID, localData.getDbUser(), localData.getDbPassword());
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                Log.d("Connected ", "Connected "+ e.getMessage());
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d("Error ","Error "+ e.getMessage());
            }
        }
        return connection;

    }

}


and query class

public class SQLQueries {
    private static Context context;
    private static MSSQLConnection connectionSQL;


    public SQLQueries(Context context){
        this.context = context;
        connectionSQL = new MSSQLConnection(context);
    }

    public static ArrayList<ItemList> getItemsFragments(String searchText ){

        Connection connect;
        int i=0;
        String query = context.getResources().getString(R.string.fragment_select_items) + searchText;
        Log.d("Items query",query);

        ArrayList<ItemList> fetchItems= new ArrayList<>();

        try {
            Connection connec = connectionSQL.connectionclass();
            if (connec != null) {
                Statement st = connec.createStatement();
                ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(query);
                while (rs.next()) {
                    i++;
                    Integer barcode = rs.getInt(1);
                    String itmSupCode = rs.getString(2);
                    String itmSection = rs. getString(3);
                    String itmType = rs.getString(4);
                    String ItmStonesName = rs.getString(5);
                    String alloycode = rs.getString(6);
                    Float ItmLPrice = rs.getFloat(7);
                    byte[] photo = rs.getBytes(8);
                    fetchItems.add(new ItemList(i,barcode,itmSupCode,itmSection,itmType,ItmStonesName,alloycode,ItmLPrice,photo));
                }
                rs.close();
                st.close();
                connec.close();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return fetchItems;
    }

}


Your Context is null, and you will need to track down why that is, wherever you are creating your SQLQueries instance. Also, please reconsider your use of JDBC on Android.

I finally solved the problem the day after I posted the problem.n the MSSQLConnection and SQLite classes I didn't pass the context from class to an other, As @CommonsWare mentioned the context was null. So in class MSSQLConnection i had to add the below line:
public MSSQLConnection(Context context){
    this.context = context;
    **this.SQLQueries=new SQLQueries(context);**
} 

and in SQLite class:
public  SQLite(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DB_Version);
    **this.context = context;**
    **this.mssqlConnection = new MSSQLConnection(context);**  
} 

and in SQLQueries class i had to remove this line
connectionSQL = new MSSQLConnection(context);

